# How to change the "Year" legends values in ggseasonplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, time-series, data-visualization

I have tried this code to rename the labels of "Year". But couldn't make it work

```
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
ggseasonplot(ts_Summary, polar = TRUE, 
             season.labels = c("Oct","Nov","Dec","Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr")) +
  ggtitle("Seasonal Trends of Data") + 
  xlab("Month") + 
  scale_fill_discrete(name= "Year", 
                      labels= c("","2016-17","2017-18","2018-19","2019-20"))
```

The `scale_fill_discrete(name= "Year", labels= c("2015-16","2016-17","2017-18","2018-19","2019-20"))` part isn't giving the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scale_fill_discrete` should be replaced by `scale_color_discrete`.
Here is an example using the `AirPassengers`dataset.

```
ggseasonplot(AirPassengers, polar = TRUE, 
             season.labels = c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul",
                               "Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec")) +
  ggtitle("Seasonal Trends of Data") + 
  xlab("Month") + 
  scale_color_discrete(name= "Year", labels= paste0("Y:",49:60)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]